# Why does this linked list give junk numbers?

Tags: c, list, data-structures, linked-list, cs50

I'm trying to write a program that creates a linked list which is updated when the user enters a number and prints the entered numbers when the user wishes to terminate the list.

The program seems to return random numbers though.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    typedef struct node
    {
        int number;
        struct node *next;
    }
    node;
    int i = 0;
    int x;
    char v;
    node *list = NULL;
    node* temp = NULL;
    x = get_int("Enter number: \n");
    list = malloc(sizeof(node));
    list -> number = x;
    list -> next = NULL;
    while(i == 0)
    {
        x = get_int("Enter number: \n");
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        n -> number = x;
        n -> next = NULL;
        for(temp = list; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp -> next)
        {
            i = 0;
        }
        temp->next = n;
        free(n);
        list = temp;
        v = get_char("Proceed? :\n");
        if(v == 'n')
        {
            break;
        }
        else if(v == 'y')
        {
            continue;
        }
        else return 1;
    }
    for(node *temp1 = list; temp1 != NULL; temp1 = temp1 -> next)
    {
        printf("%d\n",temp1 -> number);
    }
}
```

The `cs50` header file allows the usage of `get_` functions instead of using a combination of `printf` and `scanf`.

I'd like to know what has gone wrong here.

Comment: `temp = malloc(sizeof(node));` will cause memory leaks  and is not required

Comment: Fyi, it appears you want to do what is called *forward-chaining* your linked list as it is built, thereby retaining the original order (rather than build it as a LIFO structure such as a stack). It's not as complicated as you're making it out to be; [see here](https://pastebin.com/Vjx5qygF).

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of problems with the code

1. `temp = malloc(sizeof(node));` will cause memory leaks because you are over writing it with `list` after few lines
   **Sol:**    Actually you dont need to allocate memory for `temp` because it is used only for iterating over your list.
2. `temp->next = n; free(n);` the `free` after storing the next node will make the `n` free of allocated memory , but your `temp->next` still will point to that freed memory so as your `list` and accessing that is illegal.
   **Sol:**
   (a) Dont use `free(n)`
   (b) you don't need this `list = temp;` , because you have already added node at the end , doing `list = temp;` will remove existing elements from `list`.
3. `else return 1;` ,  Incase `v` is other then `n` or `y` then we return without printing the list and freeing allocated memory, you don't want that.
   **Sol:** Better thing is to break from that point, print the `list` and `free` the memory.
4. `while(i == 0)`
   you can use simply use `while(1)` and break properly when you don't want to continue any further.

Comment: How could I free the memory allocated to `n`  if using `free(n)` causes problems?

Comment: what problems? If `n` is pointing to valid memory got from `malloc` or other related function, you will not have any problem

Comment: In `(2)` you ask me to not use `free(n)`.

Comment: if you use `free` there the new node you created will not append to your list. Do you see any problem after updating the code based on my commnets

Comment: I just commented buggy code and ran here check one [here](https://onlinegdb.com/S1pEyBopw)

Answer (score 0):

I put remarks answers in code as comments :

```
while(i == 0) // advice : since i is always equals to 0, while (1) do the same job
{
    x = get_int("Enter number: \n");
    node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp = malloc(sizeof(node));  // warning : will lead to memory leak since this value is never used
    n -> number = x;
    n -> next = NULL;
    for(temp = list; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp -> next)
    {
        i = 0; // advice : not really usefull
    }
    temp->next = n;
    free(n); // ERROR : the new node is freed here so its memory may get garbage at any time
    list = temp; // ERROR : the begining of the linked list is lost here ; it now always points to the last new node
    v = get_char("Proceed? :\n");
    if(v == 'n')
    {
        break;
    }
    else if(v == 'y')
    {
        continue;
    }
    else return 1;
}
```